# Replace text between values in a json file

Tags: java, regex, json

There are parts of a JSON file I need to remove and replace with a generic value. The current data looks something like:

```
"owned": {},
[START]  "95cdecf3-3746-45ba-94bb-ad7314037108"
],
"loggedIn": false,
```

Don't ask how [START] got there :) I was attempting to replace the field with [START] [/END] but it got all messed up, and there's 650 occurences I don't feel like replacing manually.

How can I replace text surrounded by the following for all occurrences in the file?

```
[START]
],
"loggedIn": false,
```

With the following json 
line `"invited": []`? So the input above should end up looking like:

```
"owned": {},
"invited:" [],
"loggedIn": false,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.replaceAll` function.

```
String s = "\"owned\": {},\n" + 
                "[START]  \"95cdecf3-3746-45ba-94bb-ad7314037108\"\n" + 
                "],\n" + 
                "\"loggedIn\": false,";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?s)(?<=\\n|^)\\[START\\].*?(?=\\n\"loggedIn\":)", "\"invited:\" [],"));
```

**Output:**

```
"owned": {},
"invited:" [],
"loggedIn": false,
```

`(?s)` called DOTALL modifier, which makes dot in your regex to match even line breaks. `(?<=\\n|^)` Positive lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceded by a newline character or start of the line anchor. So that it would match the string `[START]` which was present at the start or otherwise it would match the string `[START]` which was at the middle or at the last in a line.

**OR**

```
(?m)^\[START\][\s\S]*?(?=\n\"loggedIn\":)
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/wF9yU4/1)

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?m)^\\[START\\][\\s\\S]*?(?=\\n\"loggedIn\":)", "\"invited:\" [],"));
```

Comment: Oh i see. Trying this now

Comment: Im seeing "[ Incomplete character class"

Comment: Where? it works for me. I think you failed to escape the `[` symbol.

Comment: note that regex101 won't support `(?<=\\n|^)`. But java does.